# Same thing displayed two times

Tags: discussion, recent-activity, information-display

When I saw my recent messages I got this:

[image]

You can see that in **Top 5 Posts** `acc` is shown two times.

Why 2 times?? Is it bug or normal happens with everyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when you accept your own answer. You get reputation twice - once for accepting an answer to your question (normally 2 rep, unless it's your own answer, then 0 rep) and once for having your answer accepted (normally 15 rep, unless it's your own question, then 0 rep).

I agree that it's a bit confusing, though.

Comment: They should simplify it. Its confusing. Any way `thnx` for sharing your knowledge with me.